# Getting a List of #define Symbols in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, mozilla, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to obtain a list of preprocessor #define'd symbols in VC++?  I know GCC has similar options to dump all effective #define symbols for the supplied .cpp/.h source files, but I am not sure if VC++ support this?

I am using a Mozilla open source project in Windows.  There are a lots of irrelevant #define for the UNIX build env causing the source code very unreadable.  I want to eliminate the irrelevant #define from the source code. The project uses Mozilla specific build scripts (automake, configure, Makefile, python scripts, and etc) to supply the symbol definitions to the compiler dynamically.  Also each source file add its own #define at different #ifdef branches making manually pre-determining the complete list of symbols for a specific build impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Macros and Constants` list in the `View` => `Class View` menu.

Comment: Thx, but it is difficult to create a VC++ project for the Mozilla source files. The Mozilla build system is very weird. It dynamically generates some .h files when we run 'make'. So far I have to use the command lines supplied to build the source files. Can I achieve the same thing without creating a VC++ project?